# How to incorporate chart.js in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, chart.js

I am new in javascript and have to use the libraries of Chart.js
I have in a jsp file the following instruction for a button

window.open("test.jsp", "width="+800+ "height="+580);

and in the test.jsp file this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>test</title>

<script type=“text/javascript”>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type=“test.jsp”>

<script type=“text/javascript”>


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var stars = [135850, 52122, 148825, 16939, 9763];
var frameworks = ['React', 'Angular', 'Vue', 'Hyperapp', 'Omi'];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: {
    labels: frameworks,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Github Stars',
        data: stars
    }]
 },
})
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to open the new window but I can't see anything inside.
I would like to all the code runs in jsp file, without delegating to js and html files outside.

Comment: Did you check your browser console ? Is there any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different problems in your code.

1. The referenced Chart.js library does not exist. Instead of `...Chart.min.js`, write `...chart.min.js` (lowercase).
2. Define your custom JS code in a `function` and execute it only once the `body` and its `canvas` are fully loaded (`<body onload="drawChart()">`).

Please take a look at below runnable `HTML` code, it should run similarly with `JSP`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawChart() {
      var stars = [135850, 52122, 148825, 16939, 9763];
      var frameworks = ['React', 'Angular', 'Vue', 'Hyperapp', 'Omi'];
      new Chart('myChart', {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: frameworks,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Github Stars',
            data: stars
          }]
        },
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="drawChart()">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code was right but I had the issue that IE (old Internet Explorer) doesn't support the new version of Chart.js (3.5.1)  :)